# ruby on rails f.select options with custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, attributes

I have a form select statement, like this:

```
= f.select :country_id, @countries.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
```

Which results in this code:

```
...
<option value="1">Andorra</option>
<option value="2">Argentina</option>
...
```

But I want to add a custom HTML attribute to my options, like this:

```
...
<option value="1" currency_code="XXX">Andorra</option>
<option value="2" currency_code="YYY">Argentina</option>
...
```

Comment: Rails doesn't provide that functionality, you'll have to create a helper to create that markup. Also, bear in mind that the example you mentioned is not valid HTML.

Comment: I know, my example is not valid html... I guess I have to change my way to get the results that I want, thk!

Comment: To current seekers, Rails does provide the functionality (looks like as of Rails 3?) Check current docs on `options_for_select`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Answer (score 374, accepted):

Rails CAN add custom attributes to select options, using the existing options_for_select helper. You almost had it right in the code in your question. Using html5 data-attributes:

```
<%= f.select :country_id, options_for_select(
    @countries.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, {'data-currency_code'=>c.currency_code}] }) %>
```

Adding an initial selection:

```
<%= f.select :country_id, options_for_select(
    @countries.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, {'data-currency_code'=>c.currency_code}] }, 
    selected_key = f.object.country_id) %>
```

If you need grouped options, you can use the grouped_options_for_select helper, like this (if @continents is an array of continent objects, each having a countries method):

```
<%= f.select :country_id, grouped_options_for_select(
    @continents.map{ |group| [group.name, group.countries.
    map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, {'data-currency_code'=>c.currency_code}] } ] }, 
    selected_key = f.object.country_id) %>
```

Credit should go to paul @ pogodan who posted about finding this not in the docs, but by reading the rails source.  https://web.archive.org/web/20130128223827/http://www.pogodan.com/blog/2011/02/24/custom-html-attributes-in-options-for-select

Answer (score 6):

You could do this as follows:

```
= f.select :country_id, @countries.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, { 'data-currency-code' => c.currency_code} ] }
```

Comment: Correct, but already mentioned in Anatortoise House's answer.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't illustrate the custom attributes using ruby. This one does hence I feels it's better as it's the first answer that shows how to do it via ruby.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible directly with Rails, and you'll have to create your own helper to create the custom attributes. That said, there are probably two different ways to accomplish what you want:

(1) **Using a custom attribute name in HTML5.** In HTML5 you are allowed to have [custom attribute names](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml), but they have to be pre-pended with 'data-'. These custom attributes will not get submitted with your form, but they can be used to access your elements in Javascript. If you want to accomplish this, I would recommend creating a helper that generates options like this:

```
<option value="1" data-currecy-code="XXX">Andorra</option>
```

(2) **Using values with custom splitting to submit additional data.** If you actually want to submit the currency-code, I would recommend creating your select box like this:

```
= f.select :country_id, @countries.map{ |c| [c.name, "#{c.id}:#{c.currency_code}"] }
```

This should generate HTML that looks like this:

```
<option value="1:XXX">Andorra</option>
<option value="2:YYY">Argentina</option>
```

Which you can then parse in your controller:

```
@id, @currency_code = params[:country_id].split(':')
```

Comment: Great answer.  I have opted for approach number 1 and blogged how I made the helper in case it helps anyone else. http://www.redguava.com.au/2011/03/rails-3-select-list-items-with-custom-attributes/

Comment: Agree with other commenters -- see Anatortoise's answer, below!

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>>>>WRONG ANSWER...KEEP SCROLLING<<<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: This is directly possible in Rails. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9076805/380607

Comment: Pan, please delete this misleading answer.

Comment: Yeah not to be a negative nelly but this really ought to be deleted

Answer (score 4):

The extra attributes hash is only supported in Rails 3.

### If you're on **Rails 2.x**, and want to override `options_for_select`

I basically just copied the Rails 3 code. You need to override these 3 methods:

```
def options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
    return container if String === container
    container = container.to_a if Hash === container
    selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)

    options_for_select = container.inject([]) do |options, element|
      html_attributes = option_html_attributes(element)
      text, value = option_text_and_value(element)
      selected_attribute = ' selected="selected"' if option_value_selected?(value, selected)
      disabled_attribute = ' disabled="disabled"' if disabled && option_value_selected?(value, disabled)
      options << %(<option value="#{html_escape(value.to_s)}"#{selected_attribute}#{disabled_attribute}#{html_attributes}>#{html_escape(text.to_s)}</option>)
    end

    options_for_select.join("\n").html_safe
end

def option_text_and_value(option)
  # Options are [text, value] pairs or strings used for both.
  case
  when Array === option
    option = option.reject { |e| Hash === e }
    [option.first, option.last]
  when !option.is_a?(String) && option.respond_to?(:first) && option.respond_to?(:last)
    [option.first, option.last]
  else
    [option, option]
  end
end

def option_html_attributes(element)
  return "" unless Array === element
  html_attributes = []
  element.select { |e| Hash === e }.reduce({}, :merge).each do |k, v|
    html_attributes << " #{k}=\"#{ERB::Util.html_escape(v.to_s)}\""
  end
  html_attributes.join
end
```

Kinda messy but it's an option. I place this code in a helper module called `RailsOverrides` which I then include in `ApplicationHelper`. You can also do a plugin/gem if you prefer.

One gotcha is that to take advantage of these methods you must always invoke `options_for_select` directly. Shortcuts like

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id, {"data-stuff"=>"html5"} ] })
```

will yield the old results. Instead it should be:

```
select("post", "person_id", options_for_select(Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id, {"data-stuff"=>"html5"} ] }))
```

Again not a great solution, but it might be worth it to get to the ever so useful data-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and created the "enhanced_select" Ruby Gem to solve this problem. You can find it here:

https://github.com/bkuhlmann/enhanced_select

Comment: This links to a 404 page on github.com

Comment: It still links to a 404. Brooke Kuhlmann please it's been 13 years and I am still looking to use your gem! I will keep checking daily...