# Rails Formtastic: adding "data-" field to option tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have:

```
form.input :duration, as: select, collection: {}
```

I need:

```
<option value="" data-price="XXX"></option>
```

Rails does not support HTML5 data attributes for the option tag. Formtastic [suggests](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/509) to create a helper method for this.

Formtastic readme [describes](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) how to extend input tags. However, in [select_input.rb](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb) I can't find any method which would affect the ***option*** tag. So, how do I do this?

Also, I found [enhanced_select](https://github.com/bkuhlmann/enhanced_select) gem which does exactly what I need, but I am not able to make it work with formtastic.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually rails does support adding any kind of html tag to options. Usually you would have:

```
options_for_select( [['First', 1], ['Second', 2]] )
```

which would give you

```
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
```

If you add a hash into the arrays for each option the hash keys/values will be added as HTML attribute to the option, e.g.

```
options_for_select( [['First', 1, {:'data-price' => 20}],
                     ['Second', 2, {:'data-price' => 30}]] )
```

will produce the required tags:

```
<option value="1" data-price="20">First</option>
<option value="2" data-price="30">Second</option>
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a model called Items, you can actually do this in formtastic like so:

```
form.select :duration, 
           collection: Items.map{|item| [item.name, item.id, {"data-price" => item.price}]}
```

Essentially what you are doing is passing an array of arrays where the final value in each array is a hash. 
E.g.

```
[  
  ['Item 1', 1, {"data-price" => '$100'}],   
  ['Item 2', 2, {"data-price" => '$200'}]
]
```

Rails 3+ (perhaps 2.x - I didn't confirm) will use the hash in such as array and simply add it to the html of the option tag. Giving you the following:

```
<option data-price="$100" value="1">Item 1</option>
<option data-price="$200" value="2">Item 2</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
options_for_select([
  ['Item 1', 1, data:{price: 121, delivery: 11}],
  ['Item 2', 2, data:{price: 122, delivery: 22}]
])
```

**Produces**

```
<option data-delivery="11" data-price="121" value="1">Item 1</option>
<option data-delivery="22" data-price="122" value="2">Item 2</option>
```

**Advantage**

Using data:{...} is more concise and if using multiple data tags can save code.