# How do I add data fields to the options for options_for_select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, form-helpers

How would I add data- fields to the options in this options_for_select? This is for Rails 2.

I'd like to add something like

```
data-masterlocation-name="<%= location.masterlocation.inst_name %>" 

data-masterlocation-id="<%= location.masterlocation.id %>"
```

to each option. I tried following this approach ([Rails Formtastic: adding "data-" field to option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624824/rails-formtastic-adding-data-field-to-option-tag/9076805#9076805)) but it doesn't seem to work for my situation. Thanks in advance for your help!

Maptry Helper:

```
module MaptryHelper

  def options_for_select(locations)
    locations.map do |location|
      [location.masterlocation.name, location_string(location.masterlocation)]
    end
  end

  def location_string(masterlocation)
    "#{masterlocation.street_address}, #{masterlocation.city}, #{masterlocation.state}, #{masterlocation.zip}"
  end

end
```

View

```
<%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations),{}, :id=>"startdrop", :name=>"startthere" %>
```

**FINAL VERSION WORKS**

Helper

```
module MaptryHelper

  def options_for_select(locations)
    locations.map do |l|
    content_tag "option", l.masterlocation.name, location_option_attributes(l)
    end.join("\n")
  end

  private

  def location_option_attributes(location)
    {
    :value => "#{location.masterlocation.street_address}, #{location.masterlocation.city}, #{location.masterlocation.state}, #{location.masterlocation.zip}",
    :id => location.masterlocation.id,  
    :"data-masterlocation-name" => location.masterlocation.name,
    :"data-masterlocation-id" => location.masterlocation.id
    }
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations), {}, {:id=>"startdrop", :name=>"startthere"} %>
```

Comment: That's actually incorrect.  You can.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624824/rails-formtastic-adding-data-field-to-option-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with this method. You can however, write like this:

```
<%= f.select :start, location_options(@itinerary),{}, :id=>"startdrop", :name=>"startthere" %>
```

And in your helper:

```
def location_options(itinerary)
  itinerary.locations.map do |l|
    content_tag "option", l.name, location_option_attributes(l)
  end.join("\n")
end

private

def location_option_attributes(location)
  {
    :id => location.id,  
    :"data-masterlocation-name" => location.masterlocation.inst_name,
    :"data-masterlocation-id" => location.masterlocation.id
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, this throws an error: `maptry_helper.rb:3: formal argument cannot be an instance variable def location_options(@itinerary) ^.` Also, in your answer, where would I put the value that I want to create: `"#{masterlocation.street_address}, #{masterlocation.city}, #{masterlocation.state}, #{masterlocation.zip}"`?

Comment: I was able to tweak the code to get it to work for me (based on your code above!) Thanks for the help. I've got several related questions out there, so appreciate any other advice you have to offer.