# Rails Formtastic: adding “data-” field to option tag with value from related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Thanks to [Rails Formtastic: adding "data-" field to option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624824/rails-formtastic-adding-data-field-to-option-tag) I got an easy solution to adding a data fieed to options in my ActiveAdmin form. But, now I want to get the data value from a different table (model). I'm a total rails newbie, trying to figure things out as I go, hoping someone can steer me right on this.

So, I have this in my ActiveAdmin form:

`att.input :attribute, :label => "Attribute:", :as => :select, :collection => AttributeDefinition.all.map { |adef| [adef.attribute_name, adef.id, {:"data-type" => AttributeInputType.where(:id => adef.input_type_id).select("input_type") } ] }`

What I'm hoping to end up with is a select element with options like this:

`<option data-type="dropdown" value="4">Voltage</option>`

But instead, I am getting options like this:

`<option data-type="#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x6adb3f8>" value="4">Voltage</option>`

This is for a Product model, which `has_many :attribute_definitions, through: :product_attributes`, and each AttributeDefinition `belongs_to :input_type, class_name: "AttributeInputType"`. So I am trying to reach the input_Type field (string) of the AtributeInputType which matches the input_type_id of the AttributeDefinition (`adef.input_type_id` above).

I can get the ID, and the data-type attribute is generated ok, so I think my problem is just basic not knowing how to pull that string field by ID. Anyone can point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this

```
AttributeInputType.where(:id => adef.input_type_id).select("input_type")
```

with

```
adef.input_type.input_type
```

`adef.input_type` returns the `AttributeInputType` object associated with `adef`. `.input_type` returns the `input_type` attribute of the `AttributeInputType` object.

In case `adef` does not have any `input_type` the above statement would throw an error. So a more robust option is

```
 adef.input_type.try(:input_type)
```

`try` returns `nil` if the associated object is not found.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I had tried before - or so I thought. I must have had a typo and then thought I had the syntax wrong, because now it works fine. Much appreciated!