# Rails 3. How to add custom attributes to a select menu?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have an Invoice.

Invoice contains LineItems(that belongs to Items).

In the invoice, there is a drop down menu to select line items. I need to add two custom attributes: **data-quantity** and **data-price**. (HTML5)

I tried to do it following this article: http://www.redguava.com.au/2011/03/rails-3-select-list-items-with-custom-attributes/ But it doesn't work with nested model attributes.

ApplicationHelper

```
def options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(collection, value_method, text_method, attr_name, attr_field, selected = nil)
  options = collection.map do |element|
    [element.send(text_method), element.send(value_method), attr_name => element.send(attr_field)]
  end
  selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)
  select_deselect = {}
  select_deselect[:selected] = extract_values_from_collection(collection, value_method, selected)
  select_deselect[:disabled] = extract_values_from_collection(collection, value_method, disabled)

  options_for_select(options, select_deselect)
end
```

_line_item_fields.html.erb

```
Product: 
<%= f.select(:item_id, options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(@items, :id, :name, 'data-quantity', :quantity), {:prompt => 'Select'}, {:class=>'product'}) %>
```

I get error: undefined method `quantity' for #Item:0x007f53380eb2

The method in the application helper most probably works well, but the problem is that LineItems belong to Item. LineItems have quantity attribute, but Items don't have a quantity attribute.

As you can see from the error, it's looking at Item, but I it really should reference LineItem.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my question Brandon :) Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [ruby on rails f.select options with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052889/ruby-on-rails-f-select-options-with-custom-attributes)

Look at the answer by [Anatortoise House](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721328/anatortoise-house)

Works great and there is no need to add a method in the Application Controller.