# Rails, collection_select and Proc

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, collections, ruby-on-rails-2, view-helpers

I have a list of states from a country, and I would like to display them a on a `<select>`. Since I am trying to show an icon that represents the flag of each state, I am using [this](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) JQuery plugin. Anyway, at this point this is a pure Rails question.

To use that plugin, I need to set a "data-image" attribute on each of `option` tags contained in this `select`.

What I have so far is:

```
<%= collection_select(:state, :code, @states, :code, 
:name, {"data-image" => lambda {|state| image_path("/flags/#{state.code}.png") }}) %>
```

I've tried in lots of ways to set the "data-image" attribute to each of `option` but so far the result is:

```
<select id="state_code" name="state[code]">
  <option value="foo">State Foo</option>
  <option value="bar" selected="selected">State Bar</option>
</select>
```

Therefore, I am not being successful to *inject* my "data-image" attribute. I've been searching for some light, and I saw [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) [api.rubyonrails] and the following example,

```
collection_select(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:disabled => lambda{|category| category.archived? }})
```

that is basically what I am looking for and mine is pretty much the same thing but it does not work. I am using Rails 2.3.11. I will be thankful with suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up solving the problem, following is the complete solution. As far as I understood, since I am using Rails 2.3 there are not helpers to support `data` prefixed attributes. It turned out that I needed to use the Rails 3 `options_for_select` helpers as pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962481/914874) answer. As a side note, instead of using the msDropDown plugin, and I ended up using the [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick). Also, instead of using `collection_select`, I've used a `select_tag`. Then basically what you have to have is:

**rails_overrides.rb**

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962481/914874
module RailsOverrides
  def options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
      return container if String === container
      container = container.to_a if Hash === container
      selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected)

      options_for_select = container.inject([]) do |options, element|
        html_attributes = option_html_attributes(element)
        text, value = option_text_and_value(element)
        selected_attribute = ' selected="selected"' if option_value_selected?(value, selected)
        disabled_attribute = ' disabled="disabled"' if disabled && option_value_selected?(value, disabled)
        options << %(<option value="#{html_escape(value.to_s)}"#{selected_attribute}#{disabled_attribute}#{html_attributes}>#{html_escape(text.to_s)}</option>)
      end

      options_for_select.join("\n").html_safe
  end

  def option_text_and_value(option)
    # Options are [text, value] pairs or strings used for both.
    case
    when Array === option
      option = option.reject { |e| Hash === e }
      [option.first, option.last]
    when !option.is_a?(String) && option.respond_to?(:first) && option.respond_to?(:last)
      [option.first, option.last]
    else
      [option, option]
    end
  end

  def option_html_attributes(element)
    return "" unless Array === element
    html_attributes = []
    element.select { |e| Hash === e }.reduce({}, :merge).each do |k, v|
      html_attributes << " #{k}=\"#{ERB::Util.html_escape(v.to_s)}\""
    end
    html_attributes.join
  end
end
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include RailsOverrides
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= select_tag(:state, options_for_select (states.map { |state| [state.name, state.code, {"data-imagesrc" => image_path("flags/#{state.code}.png"), "data-description" => "Data from #{state.name}"}]}, current_state.code)) %>
```

Here, `current_state` is the state to be selected as the default option. For instance, I store it on a `session` variable, but for the sake of simplicity it could be a `@current_state`.

Another way to solve that would be to use a modified version of [options_from_collection_for_select_with_data](http://thehungrycoder.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-options_from_collection_for_select-with-custom-attributes-for-each-option.html) so it would no be necessary to expose the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the second answer to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052889/ruby-on-rails-f-select-options-with-custom-attributes).

Basically, it involves using the `options_for_select` helper to create the custom `data` prefixed attributes.

Comment: thanks, I've upvoted your answer and posted the completed answer. At the point I saw your answer, I've already understood the options_for_select and data attributes problem on Rails 2.

Comment: I completely missed the fact that you're using Rails 2, my bad! I gotta start reading things more carefully. Glad you got things figured out though!

Comment: no problems, your link would be the North to the solution if I had not seen that question before. Thanks a ton! Cheers!