# grouped_collection_select with data attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
= grouped_collection_select :filter, :service_id, @categories, :enabled_beauty_salon_services, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: 'Choose a service'
```

But now I need to add some custom attributes like 'data-duration' to items in grouped_collection_select (not to groups - only to items!). How can I do it? Rails 4

Comment: See most rated answer
 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052889/ruby-on-rails-f-select-options-with-custom-attributes