# How to add id into options_for_select on select_tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I'm trying to implements `select_tag` on rails. And I wish to add select option on each option value with id. This is my select_tag code :

```
<%= select_tag "type", options_for_select(@form_type, :selected => form.values.first.form_type._id, id: "#{form.values.first.form_type.key}"), name: "core_template[form][#{index.to_s}][type]", class: "form-control change-type", id:"core_template_type#{index.to_s}", :prompt => "Select Type", :required=>"required" %>
```

and the select_tag generate html like below :

```
<select name="core_template[form][0][type]" id="core_template_type0" class="form-control change-type" required="required"><option value="">Select Type</option><option selected="selected" value="57562dbba3399025ca000001">Check Box</option>
<option value="57562ddaa3399025ca000003">Free Text</option>
<option value="57562dcda3399025ca000002">Radio Button</option>
<option value="57578fc6a339900db7000002">Text Area</option></select>
```

I want to add id to each option value like below :

```
<select name="core_template[form][0][type]" id="core_template_type0" class="form-control change-type" required="required"><option value="">Select Type</option><option selected="selected" value="57562dbba3399025ca000001">Check Box</option>
<option value="57562ddaa3399025ca000003" id="free_text">Free Text</option>
<option value="57562dcda3399025ca000002" id="radio_button">Radio Button</option>
<option value="57578fc6a339900db7000002" id="text_area">Text Area</option></select>
```

how to do that?
thank you master

Comment: need help, please :(

Comment: resolve it, i don't using select tag rails...i'm doing it with select option html standar :)

Comment: why .. different id for every option tag.....

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom class or ID this way. Copied directly from the documentation [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select). I have tried and tested it in a Rails v6.0.0.beta3 app and it works.

You can optionally provide HTML attributes as the last element of the array.

```
options_for_select([ "Denmark", ["USA", {class: 'bold'}], "Sweden" ], ["USA", "Sweden"])
# => <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
# => <option value="USA" class="bold" selected="selected">USA</option>
# => <option value="Sweden" selected="selected">Sweden</option>

options_for_select([["Dollar", "$", {class: "bold"}], ["Kroner", "DKK", {onclick: "alert('HI');"}]])
# => <option value="$" class="bold">Dollar</option>
# => <option value="DKK" onclick="alert('HI');">Kroner</option>
```

You can also add custom data attributes by checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374301/5012862).

NB: It might not appear in the `ul > li` tag if you inspect with the browser console, especially if you are using `options_for_select` with Select2, at least for me it didn't. Just know it is there just might not appear. I was able to confirm it is available by trying this trying - `$('.bold').val()`